# Create a Venn diagram in Python from two numeric pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn, venn

I have two pandas columns (reproducible output below)

```
{'Test_actual': {0: 160.702, 1: 113.457, 2: 91.245, 3: 53.784, 4: 40.281, 5: 39.236, 6: 37.73, 
7: 32.692, 8: 29.983, 9: 29.983, 10: 29.69, 11: 29.69, 12: 26.232, 13: 25.779, 14: 24.094, 15: 
24.094, 16: 22.46, 17: 20.731, 18: 20.731, 19: 17.367}, 'Test_predicted': {0: 24.68385875, 1: 
21.22846956, 2: 46.41633486, 3: 0.196713859, 4: 18.22344042, 5: 13.87247076, 6: 28.5820542, 7: 
59.67648307, 8: 13.95858298, 9: 20.03071567, 10: 2.73188936, 11: 2.73188936, 12: 15.57722262, 
13: 9.469598881, 14: 0.311162267, 15: 38.29214566, 16: 11.47778436, 17: 8.754663155, 18: 
19.61416015, 19: 1.858514339}}
```

I am trying to build a Venn diagram in Python. Tried to create sets, but does not work.

**IMPORTANT. I want to keep all values, not just unique.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2

col_one_list = rf_test_actual_pred_10['Test_actual'].tolist()
col_two_list = rf_test_actual_pred_10['Test_predicted'].tolist()

set1 = set(col_one_list)
set2 = set(col_one_list)
venn2([set1, set2], ('Test actual', 'Test predicted'))

plt.show()
```

Current output is wrong

[image: Current output is bad]

Expected output

**[image: strong text]**

Should I round values for overlapping, if I do not have exact values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert your columns to `list` first. Try directly using `set`:

```
>>> venn2([set(rf_test_actual_pred_10["Test_actual"].astype(int)),
           set(rf_test_actual_pred_10["Test_predicted"].astype(int))],
           set_labels=("Test actual","Test predicted"))
```

[image]

Comment: I got the same output in another attempt. How to make them overlap? Round values to integers? Why 16 and 19, if I have 20 rows in each column? Thanks

Comment: You're using `set` so you keep only unique values.

Comment: Can I keep all values?

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - That doesn't make sense for venn diagrams which are designed for `set`s. I however edited my answer to round down the values to integers.